# Learning Vim: Best way to remove space between words

Tags: vim, command, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm an experienced developer on the Windows platform and I'm trying to teach myself how to use Vim. I am pretty good with regular expressions and understand the principles of how to use Vim. However, I have a specific problem, and although I have a solution, it feels as though there ought to be a better one.

I have a file which contains a line similar to the following:

```
CODE<tab><tab>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

There could be a variable number of `<tab>` or `<space>` characters between `CODE` and `Lorem`. Assuming the cursor is over the 'C' of `CODE` in normal mode, what I want to be able to do is find a key combination that will produce the following output, and leave the cursor between the 'E' of `CODE` and he 'L' of `Lorem` in insert mode.

```
CODELorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

My curent solution is to use the following key sequence:

<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd><return></kbd>

This works, but it feels illogical to go past the thing I want to delete before I can delete it. I feel like I should move to the end of `CODE` and delete forwards. I realise this could simply be a Vim idiom that I'm not aware of. I could also be totally missing a key piece of Vim knowledge.

What's the best way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> will do it.

- <kbd>e</kbd> - move forward to the end of the word
- <kbd>l</kbd> - move 1 character to the right
- <kbd>dw</kbd> - delete all the blanks

If your cursor is in the middle of some whitespace, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> will delete whitespace left and right of the cursor. (If it is somewhere in the middle of a word, it will delete the word.)

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I actually thought this to start with, but I got hung up on the fact that 'l' moves the cursor to the end of the tab stop, rather than to the position immediately following `CODE`. Now that I try it, it kinda makes sense. I think it highlight what I was thinking though: learning Vim isn't just about the commands - it also requires learing some idioms.

Comment: @Damian: Sure, there are nice regularities throughout vi/vim, I'm still getting a handle on them myself :-)

Comment: after a little more experimentation, I think the key sequence I was looking for is `elcw`. This leaves me in insert mode, ready to add my replacement text. Awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: I think this would get you the best score in http://www.vimgolf.com/ , which I have found is a great way to hone your l33t Vim skillz.

Answer (score 4):

Some alternatives:

```
:s/\s\+//
e xx
elxx
eldtL
f<tab>xx
eldw
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Ross. I was looking to use this sequence in a snipet so one or two of your suggestions won't work because they're taking into account the exact layout and content which various from line to line in my file. Thanks for the pointers to some other stuff I didn't previously know about though.